# Plesk assign privileges to database user. "No privileges" error

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin, privileges, plesk

I am new with Plesk, I used cPlanel whole this time, and never had problems like this.

I created database on subdomain and add user to that database, and when I enter in phpMyAdmin i get error "No Privileges". I cannot connect to database trough php because of this. 
This is how it looks

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/9/unledpyzx.png/

[priv http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/9/unledpyzx.png/](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/9/unledpyzx.png/)
Thank you in advance

Comment: What privileges did you grant that user? `SHOW GRANTS FOR user@domain`.

Comment: how do I check priveleges. I entered SHOW GRANTS FOR myuser@localhost in place for querys. And i get sql error like this: #1141 - There is no such grant defined for user 'myuser' on host 'localhost'

Comment: Which means that particular user@host doesn't exist.

Comment: I have tabele users, and field username. One username is myuser. Is that ok?

Comment: Mysql users are two-parters: username, and host. user@example.com is completely separate/different from user@localhost.

Comment: I understand that, and this is how i connect to database
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","myuser",discovery);
is that ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plesk doesn't give you permissions to create databases through the phpMyAdmin tool, and instead gives you a different interface for creating databases. It looks like you've already completed that step, so you should be fine. The next thing you need to do is define your db structure, which you can do using phpMyAdmin.

Comment: yes, you will still be able to access your databases and tables just fine.